# Swift URL decoding does not decode string

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, decoding

when trying to decode the following encoded string, it does not work...it´s actually doing nothing...leaving the string as it is:

```
https://www.foodhat.app/?rOpeningTime=08:00&rClosingTime=20:00&rClosedUntil=2019-08-19&pId=557&rId=69&goTo=CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_DETAILS&cName=Duhok&pName=%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B3%D9%81+%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9&rName=Mansaf+Alzain&rMinOrderValue=15000
```

`pName` is arabic, so do not wonder the encoding of it.

I use `str.removingPercentEncoding` to decode the string...but as said...it doesn´t remove the "+" (e.g. in `rName`)!

**Result is**

```swift
let str = "https://www.foodhat.app/?rOpeningTime=08:00&rClosingTime=20:00&rClosedUntil=2019-08-19&pId=557&rId=69&goTo=CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_DETAILS&cName=Duhok&pName=%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B3%D9%81+%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9&rName=Mansaf+Alzain&rMinOrderValue=15000"

print(str.removingPercentEncoding!)
//https://www.foodhat.app/?rOpeningTime=08:00&rClosingTime=20:00&rClosedUntil=2019-08-19&pId=557&rId=69&goTo=CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_DETAILS&cName=Duhok&pName=منسف+دولمة&rName=Mansaf+Alzain&rMinOrderValue=15000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because "+" isn't percent encoded?  A percent encoded space is %20

Comment: "percent encoding" encodes only symbols not allowed in URL, but "+" is allowed symbol, so it is just present as-is.

Answer (score 1):

When decoding an URL you should use `URLComponents` :

```
let url = URL(string:"https://www.foodhat.app/?rOpeningTime=08:00&rClosingTime=20:00&rClosedUntil=2019-08-19&pId=557&rId=69&goTo=CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_DETAILS&cName=Duhok&pName=%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B3%D9%81+%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9&rName=Mansaf+Alzain&rMinOrderValue=15000")!

let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)

print(components)
```

Output is :

```
[rOpeningTime=08:00, rClosingTime=20:00, rClosedUntil=2019-08-19, pId=557, rId=69, goTo=CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_DETAILS, cName=Duhok, pName=منسف+دولمة, rName=Mansaf+Alzain, rMinOrderValue=15000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'str.replacingOccurrences()' instead. A better solution would be to use 'URLComponents', 'queryItems' to perform the filtering on the targeted queryItem, to ensure that '+' removal is not done for the entire url.